# CSS se pierde al refrescar la pagina

Tags: c#, .net, mvc

Estoy puliendo detalles de una aplicación MVC en C#, pero por alguna razón, si bien los cambios se ven cuando yo grabo mi proyecto, se pierden como por obra de magia al refrescar la página. Como pueden ver, todo incluso se "pierde" a tal punto que a la hora de inspeccionar no salen mis atributos.

**Así se ve cuando grabo mi proyecto**

[image: Asi se ve cuando grabo mi proyecto]

**Así se ve cuando actualizo la página**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías mostrar la información de tu web.config

Comment: Estas utilizando jquery o algo similar para cargar el diseño de la página?

Comment: En lugar de imágenes pesadísimas por favor coloca el código directamente

Comment: Si mal no recuerdo cuando estas corriendo el proyecto, el css se puede modificar pero no se guardan los cambios del mismo.

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionar el problema?

Answer (score 0):

@Lucas desactiva el [Browser Link](https://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link) para evitar una comunicación constante entre el explorador y el IDE (Visual Studio).

Para desactivar el Browser Link:

[image]

Comment: ¿Por qué no lo pones como comentario? Ya tienes suficiente reputación.

Comment: Si mejor me dices el por qué de no considerarla como respuesta.

Comment: No es una respuesta porque necesita clarificación del OP. Este tipo de respuestas son comentarios, como si fuese un foro normal. Una respuesta debe dar **una solución concreta** porque se supone **sabes la causa y la solución**. Si quieres que sea una respuesta válida, saca el *"quisiera"* y el *"podrías"* y pon: *"Se arregla desactivando Browser Link en el IDE"*.

Comment: Lo desactivo, pero mis cambios en CSS no se guardan ni se ven cuando inspecciono la pagina.

Comment: @Davlio . Si le pongo el atributo style dentro de mi etiqueta div todo se ve correctamente, así que sospecho que quizás no esta bien indexado el css con mi archivo html. Des-afortunadamente no encuentro donde debo hacer el vinculo. Se que es en la etiqueta <head> pero no la encuentro.